# Posing the rig pulls other parts of the mesh?

Tags: rigging

I'm rather new to Blender, and I'm attempting to rig my first character. However, when I go to pose her, I end up pulling separate parts of the model with other parts.

[image: As you can see, the character is in a neutral position.1]

[image: Then, when I move her arms, her robo-hips move with them!]

Here's the .blend, for reference:
[Wave2.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jHl4kTInr4lB6dfclXH7D3gO8Nw7PcMq/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

You made the mesh the parent of the rig. That's the wrong relationship.

Steps to fix it:

- switch to *Object* mode, select the *metarig* armature and **clear its parent** with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> *> Clear Parent*.
- **apply the *Scale* to the armature** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Scale*. (This resets the scale transformation of the object to 1.0 and it is important for the calculation of the weights. You can check the *Scale* in the N-panel.)
- select the mesh (*Wave*) and **remove the *Armature* modifier** (The mesh should be now in A-pose)
- **keep the mesh selected and select additionally the armature.** The armature must be the *active* object. This is usually the object that you selected last and it's highlighted in orange. It will be the parent. The mesh object should be highlighted in red and it will become the child.
- bind the mesh to the armature with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> ***> With Automatic Weights***

Good to know: The metarig is just a template to define the position of the bones. You can bind the mesh to it and use it as an armature. But the actual *rig* is created with the "Generate Rig" button. It's much more powerful and offers controllers & inverse kinematics (IK) for easier animation.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the issue immediately!